# Why Can't Vector Projections Between Two Vectors Be the Same

Tags: geometry, vectors

The question is as follows:

> Give two reasons why the projection of **u** onto **v** is not the same as the projection of **v** onto **u**.

I was thinking that the directions of vectors **u** and **v** are not the same so that's one way that the projections might differ. Furthermore, the length of the vectors may not be the same as well (given the exception that **u** and **v** are unit vectors in which case their length would be 1).

Are those reasons valid? If not, how can I refine them?

Comment: You're in the ballpark, but it's not quite right.  You want to say, if the vectors are different, either they differ in direction, or they have the same direction but differ in magnitude.  Then deal with each of these two cases as you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the projection of $\vec u$ onto $\vec v$ is given by

$$\vec u \cdot\frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}=|\vec u|\cos\theta$$

while the projection of $\vec v$ onto $\vec u$ is given by

$$\vec v \cdot\frac{\vec u}{|\vec u|}=|\vec v|\cos\theta$$

and thus in general

$$\vec u \cdot\frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}\neq\vec v \cdot\frac{\vec u}{|\vec u|}$$

Note that equality holds when

$$|\vec u|\cos\theta=|\vec v|\cos\theta\iff (|\vec u|-|\vec v|)\cos\theta=0 \iff |\vec u|=|\vec v|\quad \lor \quad \cos\theta=0 $$

that is if and only if the vectors have the same modulus or they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

The projectoin can be the same, if they are equal. When they are not equal, you have two cases:

- they are colinear: then the two projections are the identity on both, and so different.
- they are not colinear: the projection onto $u$ is colinear with $u$, while the projection onto $v$ is colinear with $v$.